# Fix for constructor property in protypical inheritence

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

The book "JavaScript for Ninja" suggested the following fix for constructor property while establishing prototypical chain between objects:

[image]

If I create a Person object as follow:

```
var person = new Person();
alert(person.constructor == Ninja); // Display true
```

Even though its fix the problem that ninja.constructor will refer to the Ninja function, But it creates the another problem that now person.constructor will also refer to the Ninja function instead of Person.

Reproducible Example:

```js
function Person() {

}
var person = new Person();
Person.prototype.dance = function() {};

function Ninja() {

}
Ninja.prototype = person;
Object.defineProperty(Ninja.prototype, "constructor", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: Ninja,
  writable: true
})
var ninja = new Ninja();

alert(person.constructor == Ninja); // Display true
```

I am unable to understand why this fix was suggested by the author.

Comment: When is the `Person` constructor changed?

Comment: @Drenai yes I checked, If you create a person object, var person = new Person() then person.constructor would refer to ninja function.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/gemexovoci/edit?js,console) please include a [mcve] that shows EXACTLY how you get that result.

Comment: @VLAZ updated the code

Comment: @Tarun not with a reproducible example.

Comment: This is NOT what the example shows at all! You're re-using the ibject that serves as a prototype!

Comment: @VLAZ Could you tell what should be the proper fix if I wan to reuse the object

Comment: *Why* would you want to reuse it? The purpose of the prototype is not to be used as if it's a normal instance. Hence why we assign a separate thing there. I'd say re-using `person` is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @VLAZ I am new to JS. As a norm, In other programming languages when we do Ninja extends Person, we are able to use both a person as well as Ninja object (considering both are concrete classes)

Comment: Because if you have `Ninja extends Person` in other languages, you don't link them via live objects. JS *does* use live objects, hence you assign one as the prototype. Since it's an instance, you can (and do) manipulate it. Any *other* instances created with `new Person` are completely unaffected by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only modifying the `constructor` property of that one `person` instance, not the whole `Person` class. If you do

```
person2 = new Person();
console.log(person2.constructor == Ninja);
```

it will print `false`.

Notice that in the book you quoted, it didn't even assign the `new Person()` object to a variable, it just created an anonymous object for use in creating the prototype chain.

In general, the object used in the prototype chain will not usually be used as an actual object in the application, it just serves the purpose of linking the related classes.

```js
function Person() {
}
var person = new Person();
Person.prototype.dance = function() {};

function Ninja() {
}
Ninja.prototype = person;
Object.defineProperty(Ninja.prototype, "constructor", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: Ninja,
  writable: true
})
var ninja = new Ninja();

var person2 = new Person();
console.log(person.constructor == Ninja);
console.log(person2.constructor == Ninja);
```

Comment: I think you did not get my question, if you create a person object as: var person = new Person() then person.constructor would refer to Ninja function. It is because we have a created a constructor property in Ninja.prototype (that refers to person object).

Comment: Thanks. It means I should not be using the Person object that serves the purpose of establishing prototypical chain.